# Java OOP build an array of objects

Tags: java, oop

Thanks for your help! I abandoned the advanced for loop, and it runs fine now. But the requirement still makes me confused. The requirement is to throw an exception if the test case passes more than 5 objects. But it also says "Do not use java scan, build allocation programmatically". I cannot get the point. If I do not use scan, how can I know how many objects the user passes? How can I decide whether it is more than 5 or equals 5? Or is there a way to populate an array without knowing how many objects I'm going to pass?

Teacher's requirement:
• When populating the array of Book objects, application should throw an exception, if test case passed more object than array capacity. Array capacity is defined as (nBooks = 5 ;). Do not use java scan, build allocation programmatically.
• Use ONLY ARRAY NOT LIST for this assignment.

The Book Class

```js
public class Book {
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private double price;
 
 public Book() {
  id = 0;
  name = "";
  price = 0;
 }
 
 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }
 
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 
 public void setPrice(double price) {
  this.price = price;
 }
 public double getPrice() {
  return price;
 }

}
```

The BookApp Class:

```js
public class BookApp {
    public static Book[] populateBooks() {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      Book[] books = new Book[5];
      for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
       books[i] = new Book();
       System.out.print("Enter book id: ");
       books[i].setId(input.nextInt());
       System.out.print("Enter book name: ");
       books[i].setName(input.next());
       System.out.print("Enter book price: ");
       books[i].setPrice(input.nextDouble());
      }
      return books;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But it also says "Do not use java scan, build allocation
>   programmatically". I cannot get the point. If I do not use scan, how
>   can I know how many objects the user passes? How can I decide whether
>   it is more than 5 or equals 5? Or is there a way to populate an array
>   without knowing how many objects I'm going to pass?

"build allocation programmatically" means you don't have to request or parse any user input - just write code to do it directly.

However, the requirements mention a "test case". That means you should have separate logic for managing the array (testing capacity and throwing an exception) and doing this programmatic allocation. It doesn't sound like you're expected to use a testing framework, so simply give the BookApp class the array as instance variable, an addBook() method, and do the testing in its main method.

Comment: Yes, it actually requires a JUnit test framework also. So if I don't need scan, I just make instance variable like book[0] = new Book(1, "HTLM", 56.0); in the test case, right?

Comment: @CHUCHUYAO: no, you'd call bookAppInstance.addBook(new Book(1, "HTLM", 56.0); in the test case, because you need a place to put the checking logic.